# Red5 Simple broadcaster demo is not working

Tags: red5, broadcasting

I have installed red5 on my ubuntu 13.10 (64 bit).  And I have installed readymade app oflaDemo from installer. Now when I try to access SimpleBroadCaster from 
http://mydomain.com/demos/simpleBroadcaster.html

its showing blank screen [image]

I can't figure out what is the problem. Can anyone helps me here?

Comment: I think its might be problem with some missing configuration. I downloaded red5-1.0.1 and red5-1.0.3. And, they are working fine now. I coudn't install red5-1.0.2 oflaDemo. But in 1.0.1, 1.0.3 there is no problem. And, java6 should be there to run these. If you have the same problem as above, try to give ip instead of localhost/oflaDemo and click connect. It sometimes fails because of hosts file damage